# Default key for Python builtin max/min functions

Tags: python

The documentation for the built-in functions `max` and `min` in Python indicate that the `key` parameter should operate like it does in the `sort` function. In other words, I should be able to do this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
max(a, key=None)
```

However, this raises an error:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

But, if I do something similar with the `sort` function, I get the expected results:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.sort(key=None)
```

No error is generated and the default sort is used. Several books also imply that I should be able to get away with the same behavior in the `max` and `min` functions. See this excerpt from [Python in a Nutshell](http://books.google.com/books?id=JnR9hQA3SncC&lpg=PA58&ots=Jb3UEt090u&dq=set%20key%20argument%20to%20none%20python%20max&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q=set%20key%20argument%20to%20none%20python%20max&f=false).

Is this really the default behavior of the `max` and `min` functions? Should it be? Shouldn't they match the sort function?

Comment: Not reproducible in 3.8; `max([1, 2, 3, 4], key=None)` gives `4`. I don't know exactly when this changed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You've stumbled on to a difference in the implementation of `.sort` and `max` more than a problem with the language.

`list.sort()` takes a keyword argument "key" which happens to default to None. This means that the sort method can't tell the difference between you supplying a `key=None` argument or it just taking on the default value. In either case, it behaves as if no key function has been provided.

`max` on the other hand is checking for the presence of a keyword argument "key". It does not have a default value and it's value is used as the key function if present at all.

Either way, key should never be supplied as None. It is supposed to be a function which is used to extract a "key" value from the items in the list/iterable. For instance:

```
a = [("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3), ("four", 4)]
a.sort(key=lambda item:item[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I knew that the actual implementation of these features was different, but I was sort of frustrated that all the documentation I could find did not make this difference explicit.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, accepting it is always appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

@David's answer is perfect. Just adding, in case you're wondering, the default `key` value (both in `sort` and in `max`/`min` functions) is something like:

```
lambda x: x
```

Comment: But, sort handles passing None as the default value, whereas min/max do not. So, something is being implemented differently. If you look at the code, the min and max function simply check to see if that has been defined in the argument dictionary. I don't believe there is a default value for the max/min key argument, just default behavior.